# Squares of $F_{467}$ and 7 as a quadratic residue of a prime mod that prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly is meant by this question. Could someone give me a solution with a clear explanation?

If $x=467$, are 111 127 and 225 squares in $F_x$? Explain your answer without using prime factorizations.

For what primes q, is 7 a quadratic residue modulus q? (The answer should be in terms of a set of congruence conditions on q)

Comment: $225=15^2$ as natural numbers, so $225$ is a square mod whatever you like.  For the others, well do you know what quadratic reciprocity is?

Comment: For $7$ and $q$ a standard tool is Reciprocity.  Was there a problem with using that?

Comment: havn't learned about that yet, I will look into it thanks